# When to use "reichen" vs "ausreichen" (in the sense of "to be enough")

Tags: usage

> Was ist nur mit dem Wetter los?! Wenn es auch nur noch ein bisschen kälter wird, wird es vielleicht nicht einmal **reichen**, weiterzutanzen, um mich warm zu halten!
>
> Was ist nur mit dem Wetter los?! Wenn es auch nur noch ein bisschen kälter wird, **reicht** nicht mal mehr der feurigste Tanz **aus**, um mich warm zu halten!

For instance, when I say something like this in conversation, I find myself using "reichen" in the first phrasing and "ausreichen" in the second instead of the other way around. The thing is, I can't put my finger on exactly why I feel this way.

I found a post dealing with the difference between "reichen", "ausreichen", and a few others, but I'm still none the wiser.

Answer (score 5):

**Ausreichen** means *to be sufficient in terms of level*, while **reichen** means *to be at that level*. In your example, *reichen* is used the same way as *ausreichen* because you give an explanation why something would be not sufficient.

Consider the following examples:

> Das Wasser reicht mir bis zur Hüfte.

You can't use *ausreichen* here because it's not about something being sufficient.

> Dieser Wasserstand reicht mir zum Schwimmen (aus).

You can use both *reichen* and *ausreichen*. They mean the same, it's clear from context this is about the water level being sufficient (for swimming).

The real use case for this verb *ausreichen* is the *Partizip I*.

> Das ist ein ausreichender Wasserstand.

No one uses *reichend* in this case.

Comment: Hi. So in my two sentences, are the two verbs simply interchangeable?

Comment: Yes, as both your examples are about something being (not) sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

"reichen" is more "to be enough" while "ausreichen" is "to be sufficient".  "Ausreichen" implies reaching a threshold while "reichen" implies reaching a limit.

Comment: You completely missed one use of "reichen"!

Answer (score 1):

Reichen can be translated in two ways. It can mean the same as ausreichen, which means something is enough. But reichen also can mean to give someone something.